# $\mathrm{Hom}$ and $^*\mathrm{Hom}$ for graded modules: Exercise 1.5.19(f) of Bruns-Herzog

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, graded-modules, graded-rings

Assume $R$ is a graded ring and $M$ and $N$ graded modules. Denote by $^*\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)$ the set of all homogeneous $R$-linear maps from $M$ to $N$. How can I prove that if $M$ is finitely generated then $^*\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)=\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,N)$? Do you have a counterexample of a not finitely generated module $M$ such that this equality doesn't hold?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Probably the notation should be explained ...

Comment: An answer can be also found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601970/finite-free-graded-modules-and-the-grading-of-their-duals).